# How can I get statuses of multiple documents in an envelop.

Tags: docusignapi

I have created two documents(attachments) in an envelop. I configured my account with  envelope events( signed, completed etc) to be updated to my URL(BSP) in SAP. My requirement is user may sign one document(attachemnt) and may not another(attachement).I am able to recieve the XML response from Docusign to my URL(BSP) whenever signs the document but I am not able to capture the document statuses( like signed or not signed). I checked RequestDocumentPDF() method but it retrieves only PDFBytes(attachement) seperately but not the statuses. I want to capture document statuses seperately. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to determine programmatically whether or not a Signer actually supplied a signature for an Optional **SignHereTab**.  DocuSign tracks **Recipient** status and **Envelope** status, but not **Document** status or **Tab** status. In other words:

- If **Envelope** status = **Completed**, you can safely assume that each Recipient in the envelope workflow supplied all information that the Sender marked as Required.
- If **Recipient** status = **Completed**, you can safely assume that the Recipient supplied all information that the Sender marked as Required for him/her.
- For some tab types that you specify as optional (like a **textTab**, for example), you could programmatically determine whether a Recipient provided a value by simply examining the **TabValue** property in the XML structure. Unfortunately for a **SignHereTab**, the **TabValue** property is always empty, so you can't use that to determine whether or not a signature was actually applied.

You might consider using another type of DocuSign tab (for example, a Drop Down List or Radio Button Group) to control visibility of the Signature Tab that you consider "optional". For example, let's assume that the second signature is only required if the Signer wants to agree to the additional waiver language in the contract.  You could set up the DocuSign document like this:

- Update the document to add the question "Do you agree to the additional waiver?" Then add a (***required***) DocuSign Dropdown List tab with the values "Yes" and "No" - i.e., the signer will be required to select an answer using the Dropdown list.
- Add a (***required***) Signature tab -- but make it Conditionally visible -- i.e., set tab properties such that it's only visible if the Dropdown List value "**Yes**" is selected in response to the question "Do you agree to the additional waiver?".

Then programmatically, you could check the value of the Dropdown List -- if the value is "No" then this means the second signature was NOT supplied (because the Signature Tab wouldn't have been visible to the signer) -- if the value is "Yes" then this means the second signature WAS supplied, because the Signature tab would have been visible to the Signer, and would have been required prior to the Signer being able to complete/submit the Envelope.